# Why isn't the first validation checking the second?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given this concern, included in several classes:

```
concern: Helpful do
  included do
    validates :first_reference_id, :second_reference_id, presence: true
    validates :same_parent
  end

  def same_parent
    unless first_reference.parent == second_reference.parent
      errors.add(:base, 'Parent error')
    end
  end
end
```

What would cause a `NoMethodError: undefined_method 'parent' for nil:NilClass` in the second validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is validations don't short circuit. every validation processes independent of the results of the other validations.

In order to prevent your error update the second validation to

```
def same_parent
  if first_reference &&
      second_reference &&
      first_reference.parent != second_reference.parent
    errors.add(:base, 'Parent error')
  end
end
```

This way the first validation will catch the case that one of the references is empty, and this validation will only catch the case that there is both references but they don't have the same parent